# variable may have not been initialized?

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

so in the while loop i print some elements of the ArrayList Store. but afterwards when i call it, it says array may have not been initialized.

any thoughts? i'm trying to read a file of lines. each line has at least 8 elements, and i'm sure the array is not empty because i printed from it in the while loop.

?

```
public class ReaderFile {
    public static Scanner input;
    public static Scanner input2;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count=0;
        ArrayList<Team> store;
        ArrayList<Robot> store2;
        //Robot robot;

        String fileLocation = "Tourney2Teams.csv";
        String fileLocation2 = "Tourney1robots.csv";


        try{
            input = new Scanner(new File(fileLocation)).useDelimiter(",");
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            System.out.print("PROBLEM");
        }


        try {
            input2 = new Scanner(new File (fileLocation2)).useDelimiter(",");
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            System.out.print("problem with robot");
        }


        try{
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("PLEAse\n");
                int countt = 0;
                while(input.hasNext())
                {
                        //int countt = 0;
                        int ID = input.nextInt();
                        String teamName = input.next();
                        String coachFirst = input.next();
                        String coachLast = input.next();
                        String mentorFirst = input.next();
                        String mentorLast = input.next();
                        String teamFs = input.next();
                        String teamSS = input.next();
                        input.nextLine();
                        store = new ArrayList<>();
                        Team team = new Team (teamName, ID, coachFirst, coachLast,mentorFirst,mentorLast,teamFs,teamSS);
                        store.add(team);
                        System.out.print("Team Numer"+store.get(0).teamNumber+"\n");
                        countt = countt+1;
                        System.out.print("\n"+countt);
                }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException statExcemtion)
        {
            System.out.print("\nAnkosh");
        }
        String x = store.get(2).teamName;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the file is empty? Then what will `store` be?

Answer (score 0):

```
store = new ArrayList<>();
```

This line reinitializes the store at every pass in the `while`. You probably want to initialize it before the `while` to accumulate while looping.

It says it was not initialized because for some reason it never executed the while loop (empty input).

Answer (score 0):

It can be uninitialized in two cases:

1. A `NoSuchElementException` exception is thrown in your try block, in which case your `catch` block is executed, and the `store` is not initialized. I would suggest to either `return` from the `catch` block, or move your `String x =` line inside the `try` block.
2. Your loop does zero iterations. In this case the `store` is also uninitialized. It also looks like a logic error, you probably want your `store` to be instantiated before the `while` loop.

I would also suggest to check that the `store` has at least three elements before accessing element `2`.